# How do I get my dictionary values to print on the same line as the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I have tried adding (end = "") at the end of my print statements, but the values keep printing on a new line

```
for line in file:
    errorDict[line] = errorDict.get(line, 0) + 1

for i, n in errorDict.items():
    print (str(i) + str(":") + str(n))
```

It currently looks like this

```
5262200
:2
5DAA200
:1
531G200
:3
5700H3H
:1
5300A52
:2
```

I would like it to look like

```
5262200 : 2
5DAA200 : 1
531G200 : 3
5700H3H : 1
5300A52 : 2
```

Comment: str(i).rstrip()

Comment: `errorDict = collections.Counter(line.rstrip("\n") for line in file)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the keys in your `dict` have a newline at the end. You can `strip()` them out before printing.

```
print (str(i).rstrip() + str(":") + str(n))
```

or before adding to the dict:

```
errorDict[line.strip()] = errorDict.get(line, 0) + 1
```

Comment: The latter is probably a better idea.